# how to focus on a div element in webview use code in android development

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I had a question while I try to focus on a div element in **webview** in Android development. I had set editable for the div element. However, no matter that I use `webView.requestFocus()` or `document.getElementById('container').focus()` or both, it never works. So I want to know how to get focus for `div` element in **webView**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your div loading event is generated with js. Can you set tab index attribute and give a try

http://jsfiddle.net/QAkGV/

```
<div id="generate">

$("#generate").attr('tabindex',-1).focus(function () {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I had try your ways, but it didn't work. The HTML is loaded in the WebView component in Android. I thought maybe I need not only JavaScript but also Java to work it out. Unluckily, I can't work it.